# MySQL - How to paginate through specific number of rows?

Tags: mysql, pagination

Lets say I have 5000 rows in my database. I want to paginate through the results, but I only want to paginate through the last 1000 rows, not all 5000. How would I do that? I would have a query like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT 0,25
```

But this query would grab all 5000 results. I just want to grab the latest 1000 results and paginate through that. How would I do this? I do have an id field that is a primary key, auto increment. Dont know if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use SQL for the pagination you need to call these queries in succession:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT 1000,25
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT 1025,25
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT 1050,25
...
...
```

In other words

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT <offset>,<pageSize>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM table) - 1000);
```

or this one:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000) AS ttbl ORDER BY
                                                                              id ASC;
```

Comment: The second one is better as the first does not guarantee 1000 rows to be returned if there are gaps in the ids.